# Pointers and all that [C]

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

well, I'm trying to create a simple program that simply print the name of a list of students, the thing is,I do all that's required but when I try to print all the elements come out as the same. It's in portuguese but I don't think it should be a problem.

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct struct_t{

   char * nome;
   int * notas; 


}DADOS_ALUNOS;

typedef struct struct_s{

    DADOS_ALUNOS total_alunos;


}ALUNOS;

int main (){

         
    ALUNOS * Classe;
    DADOS_ALUNOS aluno;
    int numero_alunos, quantidade_provas, i;


    printf("Digite a quantidade de alunos\n");
    scanf("%d", &numero_alunos);
    printf("Agora, digite a quantidade de provas dadas\n");
    scanf("%d", &quantidade_provas);

    printf ("Total numeoro alunos: %d\n", numero_alunos);

    Classe = (ALUNOS *) malloc (numero_alunos * sizeof(ALUNOS));
    aluno.nome = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    for (i = 0; i < numero_alunos; i++){

        printf("Digite o nome do aluno\n");
        scanf("%s", aluno.nome);

       //printf("O que está contindo na variavael temporaria: %s", aluno.nome);
        
        Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = (char *) malloc (sizeof(aluno.nome));
        Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = aluno.nome;
        //printf("O que está contindo na variavael : %s", Classe[i].total_alunos.nome);
        //free(aluno.nome);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < numero_alunos; i++){

        printf("Nome: %s\n", Classe[i].total_alunos.nome);

    }



    return 0;
}
```

any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: To copy a string, you need to use strcpy. You cannot do this by assignment.

Comment: All the `Classe[i].total_alunos.nome` are pointing to the same `aluno.nome`. And you should use a proper title for your question which is summarizing your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these statements:

```
    Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = (char *) malloc (sizeof(aluno.nome));
    Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = aluno.nome;
```

there are produced memory leaks.

At first memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `Classe[i].total_alunos.nome` and then the pointer was reassigned with the address of the memory allocated before the for loop:

```
    Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = aluno.nome;
```

At least you need to use the string function `strcpy` like:

```
    strcpy( Classe[i].total_alunos.nome, aluno.nome );
```

provided that you allocated enough space for the array pointed to by the pointer `Classe[i].total_alunos.nome` because in this allocation

```
Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = (char *) malloc (sizeof(aluno.nome));
```

you allocating memory only for pointer. That is `sizeof(aluno.nome )` is equal to `sizeof( char * )`.

However pay attention to that there will be still a memory leak because the memory pointed to by the pointer `aluno.nome` was not freed.

There is no great sense to declare an object of the type `DADOS_ALUNOS`:

```
DADOS_ALUNOS aluno;
```

and then dynamically allocate memory:

```
aluno.nome = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * 20);
```

Instead you could declare just a character array as for example:

```
char nome[20];
```

and use this array in the for loop:

```
scanf( " %19[^\n]", nome );
       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.

First, change

```
Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = (char *) malloc (sizeof(aluno.nome));
```

to

```
Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = malloc( strlen( aluno.nome ) + 1 );
```

As of C89 casts on `malloc` are unnecessary, and under the C89 standard can suppress a useful diagnostic.

The type of the expression `aluno.nome` is `char *`, so `sizeof( aluno.nome )` gives you the size of the *pointer*, not the size of the buffer it points to. Use `strlen` to get the length of the input string, then add 1 to account for the terminator.

Next, change

```
Classe[i].total_alunos.nome = aluno.nome;
```

to

```
strcpy( Classe[i].total_alunos.nome, aluno.nome );
```

The `=` operator is not defined to copy the contents of one array to another - in order to do that you have to use a library function like `strcpy` or `memcpy`, or copy elements individually in a loop.  All you are doing here is assigning the pointer value stored in `aluno.nome` to `Classe[i].total_alunos.nome`, and in the process you're losing the reference to the memory you allocated with `malloc`, leading to a memory leak.

Finally, instead of using `scanf` to read string input, use `fgets` - it makes it easier to prevent a buffer overrun:

```
printf("Digite o nome do aluno\n");
fgets( aluno.nome, 20, stdin );
```

This will read at most 19 characters into `aluno.nome` and terminate the string.  You can do that with `scanf` as well:

```
scanf( "%19s", aluno.nome );
```

but the lengths have to be hardcoded in the conversion specifier; you can't use `*` to specify a length at runtime like you can with `printf`.

Comment: You could use the pre-processor with limited results. `#define MAX 19, #define XQUOTE(x) #x, #define QUOTE(x) XQUOTE(x), char nome[MAX + 1]; scanf("%" QUOTE(MAX) "s", nome);`